# Laravel `jwt.refresh` token?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, jwt

I'm using the `tymon/jwt-auth` package for authentication an api with Laravel. It's working quite well and I have everything working properly.

However I'm unsure how to setup the `jwt.refresh` token middleware. I'm under the assumption that it will "auto-refresh" the token when expired?

I've add both to my middleware but can't seem to make it work.

```
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'api/v1',
    'namespace' => 'Api\v1',
    'middleware' => ['jwt.auth', 'jwt.refresh']
], function ($app) {

    // Routes here

});
```

Perhaps I'm not sure how it works exactly, do I need to do polling for a some refresh end point. I kind of thought that was what the middleware was supposed to do automatically per request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the `jwt.refresh` middleware, the token is refreshed on every request.  It's returned as a header on the response, so you need to take that header and store the new token on every request.

The returned Authorization header will be of the form `Token: xxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Ya, ok. That makes sense. I think I just misunderstood something I read somewhere :P Thx.

Comment: @Jeff, how do you prevent 401 when you have multiple concurrent ajax calls?